# Angular 7 & Typescript - How can I check if dynamic required checkbox is checked in order to disable button

Tags: angular, typescript

If the required checkbox is true, I want to enable the button. 
I have a file.reducer.ts file that has button and checkbox properties, file.component.html that loops through the checkbox and buttons, and file.component.ts where I want to check if the required checkbox is checked enable then enable the button. This is where I am not sure how to check for the correct checkbox and disable the button (***event.target == requiredCheckbox***).

**file.component.html:**

```
      <div *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxes">

    <label class="cui-overlay__checkbox-container">
      {{checkbox.content}}
      {{checkbox.required ? '(Required)' : '(Optional)'}}

      <input type="checkbox" (change)="isChecked($event)">

      <span class="cui-overlay__checkbox-check"></span>

    </label>

  </div>

  <ul
    [attr.data-stack]="stack"
    class="cui-overlay__buttons">

    <li
      *ngFor="let button of buttons"
      class="cui-overlay__button">

      <cui-button
        (buttonPress)="onPress($event)"
        [state]="button"
        [disabled]="button.disabled">
      </cui-button>

    </li>

  </ul>
```

**file.component.ts:**

```
  get buttons() {
    return this.state.buttons
  }

  get checkboxes() {
    return this.state.checkboxes
  }

  get contents() {
    return this.state.contents
  }

  get stack() {
    return this.state.stack
  }

  get title() {
    return this.state.title
  }

  get visible() {
    return this.state.visible
  }

  onPress(button) {
    console.log(button.value)
  }

  isChecked(event) {
    var requiredCheckbox = this.state.checkboxes.find(checkbox => checkbox.required === true);
    console.log(requiredCheckbox);
    for (let button of this.state.buttons) {
      if (button.value === "Submit Application" && event.target == requiredCheckbox) {
        button.disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

**file.reducer.ts:**

```
    buttons: [
        {
          circle: false,
          icon: null,
          iconColor: 'primary-dark',
          shadow: true,
          text: 'Disabled Button Enabled once Required is checked',
          type: ButtonType.PRIMARY,
          value: 'Submit Application',
          disabled: true
        },
        {
          circle: false,
          icon: null,
          iconColor: 'primary-dark',
          shadow: true,
          text: 'Cancel',
          type: ButtonType.SECONDARY,
          value: 'Review Application',
          disabled: false
        }
      ],
      checkboxes: [
        {
          content: 'This checkbox is not required',
          required: false
        },
        {
          content: 'This is the required checkbox.',
          required: true
        }
      ],

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is an extremely confusing question, as you have the overloaded term 'checkboxes' referring to both HTML checkboxes and the 'checkboxes' array in your reducer. Please clarify. You could edit your question using a qualifying word such as 'html' or 'reducer' before each use of the word 'checkbox' or 'checkboxes'. Also,  you cane use 'checked' and 'unchecked' when referring to whether an html input type="checkbox" is checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a variable to true/false in file.component.ts, then check that variable in your html file. the button will say [disabled]="variable"

Comment: I'm not sure how to make sure it's the required checkbox is the one that is checked in order to set the variable to true/false.

Comment: your required checkbox has an onchange event "isChecked." in your .ts file, create a global variable called "checkboxIsChecked" or something and set it to false. when it's checked, set checkboxIsChecked to true in the isChecked() function. then, your button (which has [disabled]="checkboxIsChecked") will be enabled. when it's unchecked, set it to false and the button will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML file write:

```
<mat-checkbox class="small-text" (change)="onChkChange($event)" [(indeterminate)]="isIndeterminate" color="warn"> {{item}} </mat-checkbox>
```

And the TS file:

```
isIndeterminate = false;


onChkChange() {
    console.log('Checked value changed.');
    if(!this.isIndeterminate){
      console.log('Hi');
    }
  }
```

Every time the checkbox is checked, 'Checked value changed' is printed on console and inDeterminate value changes to !indeterminate,